# Limitation of the Data Science site's migration process

Tags: feature-request, migration

Currently, *Data Science* site has no ability to specify what *StackExchange* site a question should be migrated to. This feature exists on some other sites, for example, *Cross Validated*. I think that this issue should be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Relevant FAQ on MSE: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/335251)

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about this but I think the list of sites you see may be a function of which sites you have some minimum rep on? For example I know the list on SO that I see is different from others. As a mod here I can migrate anywhere.

So it might be by design and at least it is something that I dont know how to change directly. I would not mind if everyone could vote to migrate to the 3 most common destinations, SO, Cross Validated and Open Data.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts (+1). I agree that an ability to migrate to the three sites you've mentioned would make sense, as those are the sites most closely connected to the topics discussed on this one. BTW, I don't understand my status on this site - it says that I'm moderating it, but my access to moderation tools seems to lack an ability to migrate questions. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hm I dont recall more mods being added beyond the initial three. You don't show up with a diamond. Something says you're moderating?

Comment: Somewhere on my DS profile page, I used to see the phrase saying: "You are moderating this site", but can't find it now. Anyway, per [site priviliges](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), based on my reputation, I indeed have access to moderator tools. However, I guess, that's not exactly the same as being a designated moderator.